# Select JPA e Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

Tenho cinco entidades (Cotacao, Setor, Parceiro, Itens e ItensLancados), onde o usuário irá selecionar uma cotação e setor e a relação de todos os itens relacionados a este setor irá aparecer, juntamente com os itens que já foram lançados (caso possuam).

Utilizei o seguinte select para trazer os registros:

```
String jpql = "SELECT i "
            + "FROM Itens i "
            + "INNER JOIN i.setor s "
            + "LEFT JOIN i.itensLancados il "
            + "ON il.parceiro.codParceiro = 50 AND il.cotacao.codCotacao = 1 "
            + "WHERE s.codSetor = 1";
```

Mas pelo fato de a entidade ItensLancados estar como EAGER, está me trazendo todos os registros desta tabela, ignorando a restrição de código de parceiro e código de cotação.

Tentei Utilizar o fetch após o LEFT JOIN, mas aí não consigo utilizar a cláusula ON, e se tento jogar a restrição da clásula ON para o WHERE ele não funciona, pois irá filtrar somente os dados da tabela ItensLancados, não trazendo todos os itens.

Alguém teria alguma dica de como tentar resolver este caso?

Relacionamentos

**Cotacao**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cotacao", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ItensLancados> itensLancados;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "cotacao_parceiro", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cotacao_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parceiro_id"))
private List<Parceiro> parceiros;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "cotacao_setor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cotacao_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "setor_id"))
private List<Setor> setores;
```

**Setor**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "setor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Itens> itens;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "setores", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Cotacao> cotacoes;
```

**Parceiro**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parceiro", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ItensLancados> itensLancados;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parceiros", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Cotacao> cotacoes;
```

**Itens**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "itens", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ItensLancados> itensLancados;

@ManyToOne
private Setor setor;
```

**ItensLancados**

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cotacao_id")
private Cotacao cotacao;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
private Itens itens;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parceiro_id")
private Parceiro parceiro;
```

O Select que gostaria de converter para JPQL é o seguinte:

```
    SELECT *
FROM ITENSLANCADOS RIGHT JOIN ITENS
ON ITENSLANCADOS.ITEM_ID = ITENS.IDITENS
AND itenslancados.cotacao_id = 50
and itenslancados.parceiro_id = 1
WHERE setor_codsetor = 1
```

Segue o SQL gerado pelo JPA.

```
select
    itens0_.idItens as idItens1_1_0_,
    itenslanca2_.cotacao_id as cotacao_1_2_1_,
    itenslanca2_.item_id as item_id2_2_1_,
    itenslanca2_.parceiro_id as parceiro3_2_1_,
    itens0_.codigoPlu as codigoPl2_1_0_,
    itens0_.descricaoItem as descrica3_1_0_,
    itens0_.eanItem as eanItem4_1_0_,
    itens0_.embalagem as embalage5_1_0_,
    itens0_.setor_codSetor as setor_co7_1_0_,
    itens0_.statusItem as statusIt6_1_0_,
    itenslanca2_.dataLancamento as dataLanc4_2_1_,
    itenslanca2_.qtdDigitada as qtdDigit5_2_1_,
    itenslanca2_.valorDigitado as valorDig6_2_1_,
    itenslanca2_.item_id as item_id2_1_0__,
    itenslanca2_.cotacao_id as cotacao_1_2_0__,
    itenslanca2_.item_id as item_id2_2_0__,
    itenslanca2_.parceiro_id as parceiro3_2_0__ 
from
    Itens itens0_ 
inner join
    Setor setor1_ 
        on itens0_.setor_codSetor=setor1_.codSetor 
left outer join
    ItensLancados itenslanca2_ 
        on itens0_.idItens=itenslanca2_.item_id 
left outer join
    ItensLancados itenslanca3_ 
        on itens0_.idItens=itenslanca3_.item_id 
inner join
    Parceiro parceiro4_ 
        on itenslanca3_.parceiro_id=parceiro4_.codParceiro 
        and (
            parceiro4_.codParceiro=1
        ) 
inner join
    Cotacao cotacao5_ 
        on itenslanca3_.cotacao_id=cotacao5_.codCotacao 
        and (
            cotacao5_.codCotacao=50
        ) 
where
    setor1_.codSetor=1
```

Comment: Antes de tudo... remover este `EAGER` é uma opção? Em geral, usar `EAGER` traz muito mais problemas do que soluções.

Comment: Você não pode fazer a consulta retornar itens lançados ao invés de Item?

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha visto. Então, mas se inverter e colocar o WHERE com as condições de parceiro e cotação ele vai limitar o resultado a apenas os itens lançados e não irá trazer os itens que não foram lançados, mesmo utilizando o RIGHT JOIN. Tentei fazer no BD a consulta desta maneira (invertendo a lógica) e também não rolou.

Comment: Você tem a consulta em SQL que gostaria de fazer com o JPQL? Se der, coloca no http://sqlfiddle.com/. Estou sem entender direito o que gostaria.

Comment: Dá uma olhada se consegue acessar.. 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/84e71

Comment: Legal, mas o SQL que você gostaria que virasse um JPQL, você pode colocar lá também?

Comment: Atualizei lá.. Verifica se aparece por favor

Comment: Não aparece o SQL. O link está correto?

Comment: Então, está .. mas não sei pq o SQL não apareceu.. atualizei lá no enunciado com o SQL que eu gostaria de utilizar.

Comment: Estou querendo ver o resultado da consulta, mas o SQL Fiddle está com dificuldades... tentarei novamente mais tarde.

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
String jpql = "SELECT i "
            + "FROM Itens i "
            + "JOIN i.setor s "
            + "LEFT FETCH JOIN i.itensLancados il "
            + "LEFT JOIN i.itensLancados ilJoin "
            + "JOIN ilJoin.parceiro parceiro WITH parceiro.codParceiro = 50"
            + "JOIN ilJoin.cotacao cotacao WITH cotacao.codCotacao = 1"
            + "WHERE s.codSetor = 1";
```

Não lembro como o Hibernate resolve uma query na qual, dentro na cláusula `ON` você aplica outras operações de `JOIN` (`il.parceiro` e  `il.cotacao`), tal como você fez na pergunta. Na verdade, nem lembrava que o JPQL suportava `ON`... sempre usei o `WITH` (que é o `ON`do JPQL/HQL)

Comment: Então, fiz o teste e desta forma ele me retorna também os materiais lançados por outros parceiros. Vi o retorno do SQL que ele gera, e deveria realmente ter uma condição AND no LEFT JOIN da entidade ItensLancados..

Comment: Sim, já até removi.

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Veja se funciona.

Comment: Fiz uma pequena mudança neste select que você havia enviado, adicionando o WITH no LEFT JOIN dos ItensLancados, mas quando printo na tela, ele acaba fazendo um novo select na itenslancados com o where de apenas o item, aí ele pega o lançamento de um outro parceiro.

Comment: Vou verificar agora..

Comment: Também não funcionou, pq no SQL gerado ele acaba fazendo um LEFT JOIN somente com a condição do código do item, aí ele acaba trazendo o lançamento de todos os parceiros, não somente do 50.

Comment: @IsmaelJunior, Sobre vir itens lançados de outros parceiros, isto vai ocorrer mesmo. Quando você faz FETCH/EAGER de i.itensLancados, todos os itens lançados de qualquer Item que a consulta trouxer no resultado vão vir juntos. Tem como filtrar isto no `WHERE`, mas não entendi porque isto não ajudou você... Em geral, não é recomendado filtrar relacionamentos que usam `FETCH`. Alguns frameworks JPA nem suportam alias no `FETCH` por causa disto...

Comment: É então, mas isso que queria evitar. Ele deveria trazer somente os itens referentes aquele parceiro e cotação. Pena que o WITH e o FETCH não funcionam na mesma entidade (Hibernate), senão resolveria o problema..

Comment: Vou meu comentário na sua pergunta? Acho que tu precisa inverter a lógica da consulta.

Comment: @IsmaelJunior, alterei a consulta, veja o resultado. É para ficar parecido [com isto](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/84e71/8/2).

Comment: Olá @Dherik, tentei com essa nova consulta e o resultado não me retorna nenhuma linha. Até tentei mudar os JOINS das tabelas parceiro e cotacao para RIGHT JOIN, mas também não retorna. Se eu mudar para LEFT JOIN, ele traz os lançamentos, porém não respeita a condição do parceiro e cotação.

Comment: Consegue pegar o SQL gerado pela consulta que passei? Quero entender o que o JPA está fazendo de diferente da consulta que eu esperava que ele fizesse... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/84e71/8/2

Comment: Está atualizado lá no enunciado.

Comment: Vi o SQL... consigo pensar em mais de uma maneira no SQL de resolver este problema, mas no JPQL estou pensando rs. Pior que o SQL Fiddle ainda está com problemas hj, está complicado testar

Comment: Exato, com SQL também tenho algumas maneiras para resolver, mas com JPQL estou patinando faz alguns dias.

Answer (score 1):

#### Vamos às observações:

**1ª)** `INNER JOIN i.setor s`  << esse JOIN é desnecessário

Quando você mapeia as tabelas e as relações entre elas no hibernate, ele já realiza esses joins automaticamente em suas querys.

Os `JOINs` são necessários quando estamos buscando arrays, no seu caso o `i.itensLancados`

**2ª)** Não utilize **EAGER**, utilize o **LAZY**

Com o EAGER o Hibernate sempre irá buscar a lista que você mapeou antes mesmo de você filtrá-la na query. Com o LAZY você tem mais controle das suas operações, pois faz apenas como e quando quer.

**3ª)** Para buscar arrays usando `HQL` você deve usar o `LEFT JOIN FETCH` ou `JOIN FETCH`

Para o `Hibernate`, é como se fosse um `SELECT` separado em que ele busca os elementos do `array` e preenche ele para você

---

#### Vamos à query:

Pelo que eu entendi:

- Um setor possui uma lista de itens e uma lista de cotações.
- Uma cotação possui uma lista de itensLancados

Então a sua query deverá buscar pelo setor: assim ela trará os itens daquele setor, você filtra a lista de cotação para buscar a cotação que procura e dentro da cotação você terá os itens lançados.

Correto?

```
SELECT s
  FROM Setor s
  INNER JOIN FETCH s.cotacoes cotacoes
  INNER JOIN FETCH cotacoes.parceiros parceiros= 50
  WHERE 1=1 
    AND s.codSetor = 1
    AND cotacoes.codCotacao = 1
    AND parceiros.codParceiro
```

Assim você terá um Setor com os itens daquele setor, e uma "lista de cotação" (que no caso terá apenas a cotação com codCotacao = 1 dentro), e nessa cotação você terá os itensLancados

Para o erro relatado causado pelas multiple bags, leia essas 2 referências:

[guj](http://www.guj.com.br/java/238010-hibernate--cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

[devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/controlando-multiplas-colecoes-com-hibernate/25999)

Comment: Não é recomendado fazer consultas usando o alias de um `FETCH JOIN`. O resultado disto normalmente não é o esperado.